# Splitting IP suite?

Tags: network

Is it possible to split the TCP/IP suite layers? I mean to get the original data packet with its all headers & trailers out of the Link Layer before delivering them to the physical medium, and then manipulating them in some way and then re-sending them to the application layer of the same IP suite?[image]

Sorry for my bad graph & Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes.

You can do this with `SOCK_RAW` in C/Linux. Though it is possible that the driver will overwrite some fields.

You can find more information on the man page here http://linux.die.net/man/7/packet

Btw. your graph is not correct. Packets are received from the bottom and sent from the top.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have both the 'link layer' and 'physical layer' in your graphic, I assume you really meant 'data link layer' a.k.a. Layer 2.  'Link layer' itself refers to a combination of Layer 1 and Layer 2.

It looks like you're trying to intercept fully crafted packets before they are transmitted on the network.  After interception you want to tamper with the packets, and then directly transmit that packet (re-insert into layer 1).

There are numerous devices which support lawful intercept of either layer 3 or layer 2 traffic. Cisco makes some I think.

You could always use a proxy, which would intercept the data and perform any modification necessary, except most of those would unwrap the packet, and rewrap it.

Maybe you could explain what you are trying to accomplish. There is likely an easier way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a TCP/IP route to the host machine routing table. i.e.

```
route ADD “network” MASK “subnet mask”  “gateway ip”
```

Where network and subnet will be set for the packets you want to loop back and gateway ip wil be 127.0.0.1